# how to parse complex xml in php

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml document and I'm trying to parse it ( loop through the items ) but it seems no xml parser understands it. I've tried simpleXml and few others but they provide only two fields (@attributes: locale, country) or unclear arrays. Using an [online viewer](http://xmlgrid.net/) I can clearly see the list of items so it must be an issue with the php parser. 
   Basically I need to extract each item with image, price and location. Any help to decode this in an array would be highly appreciated !
 I basically need to loop through the 'Ad' array and extract the information for each 'ad'. id, price, title, start-date-time, category, locations, pictures (array). Here is a print-screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fczhs.png . SO doesn't let me post the image without 10 reputation.

```
$xml =  simplexml_load_file('xml');
print_r($xml);
```

returns

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [locale] => en_GB
            [version] => 1.17
        )

)
```

I also tried a class I've found ( XML2Array ) with no luck ! I was thinking to use regex as it's an old friend of mine but the data doesn't seem be structured in a such way to extracted  with regex.

```
$array = XML2Array::createArray($xml);
print_r($array);
```

Below is the XML. I also pasted it on pastebin.com/XiKbfhV5 .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ad:ads xmlns:types="http://www.domainclassifiedsgroup.com/schema/types/v1" xmlns:cat="http://www.domainclassifiedsgroup.com/schema/category/v1" xmlns:loc="http://www.domainclassifiedsgroup.com/schema/location/v1" xmlns:ad="http://www.domainclassifiedsgroup.com/schema/ad/v1" xmlns:feat="http://www.domainclassifiedsgroup.com/schema/feature/v1" xmlns:attr="http://www.domainclassifiedsgroup.com/schema/attribute/v1" xmlns:pic="http://www.domainclassifiedsgroup.com/schema/picture/v1" xmlns:user="http://www.domainclassifiedsgroup.com/schema/user/v1" xmlns:rate="http://www.domainclassifiedsgroup.com/schema/rate/v1" xmlns:reply="http://www.domainclassifiedsgroup.com/schema/reply/v1" xmlns:feed="http://www.domainclassifiedsgroup.com/schema/feed/v1" xmlns:order="http://www.domainclassifiedsgroup.com/schema/order/v1" xmlns:payment="http://www.domainclassifiedsgroup.com/schema/payment/v1" locale="en_GB" version="1.17">
  <ad:ad id="1046911987">
    <ad:title>Wanted Apple Macbook pro - Air - Retina - iMac Call now Wanted Today</ad:title>
    <ad:ad-status>
      <ad:value>ACTIVE</ad:value>
    </ad:ad-status>
    <ad:start-date-time>2014-01-31T17:54:24.000Z</ad:start-date-time>
    <feat:features-active>
      <feat:feature-active display="true" name="AD_GP_TOP_AD" group="standard"/>
    </feat:features-active>
    <cat:category id="188">
      <cat:id-name>computing-phones-wanted</cat:id-name>
      <cat:localized-name>Computing &amp; Phones</cat:localized-name>
    </cat:category>
    <loc:locations>
      <loc:location id="124">
        <loc:id-name>wimbledon</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>Wimbledon</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
      <loc:location id="10000392">
        <loc:id-name>uk</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>United Kingdom</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
      <loc:location id="10000393">
        <loc:id-name>england</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>England</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
      <loc:location id="375">
        <loc:id-name>south-west-london</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>South West London</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
      <loc:location id="10000344">
        <loc:id-name>london</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>London</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
    </loc:locations>
    <pic:pictures>
      <pic:picture>
        <pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/MzE3WDU1MA==/z/I8wAAMXQVT9S6-LI/$_80.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="preview" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/MzE3WDU1MA==/z/I8wAAMXQVT9S6-LI/$_81.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="big" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/MzE3WDU1MA==/z/I8wAAMXQVT9S6-LI/$_79.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/MzE3WDU1MA==/z/I8wAAMXQVT9S6-LI/$_78.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/MzE3WDU1MA==/z/I8wAAMXQVT9S6-LI/$_77.JPG"/>
      </pic:picture>
    </pic:pictures>
  </ad:ad>
  <ad:ad id="1046911555">
    <ad:price>
      <types:currency-iso-code>
        <types:value localized-label="£">GBP</types:value>
      </types:currency-iso-code>
      <types:amount>140</types:amount>
    </ad:price>
    <ad:title>Hillbilly Golf Trolley with batteries, Trolley Bag, Callaway Golf Clubs</ad:title>
    <ad:ad-status>
      <ad:value>ACTIVE</ad:value>
    </ad:ad-status>
    <ad:start-date-time>2014-01-31T17:50:21.000Z</ad:start-date-time>
    <feat:features-active>
      <feat:feature-active display="true" name="AD_GP_TOP_AD" group="standard"/>
    </feat:features-active>
    <cat:category id="160">
      <cat:id-name>golf-equipment</cat:id-name>
      <cat:localized-name>Golf Equipment</cat:localized-name>
    </cat:category>
    <loc:locations>
      <loc:location id="10000373">
        <loc:id-name>york</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>York</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
      <loc:location id="11000029">
        <loc:id-name>north-yorkshire</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>North Yorkshire</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
      <loc:location id="10000392">
        <loc:id-name>uk</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>United Kingdom</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
      <loc:location id="10000393">
        <loc:id-name>england</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>England</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
    </loc:locations>
    <pic:pictures>
      <pic:picture>
        <pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/390AAOxygPtS695L/$_80.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="preview" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/390AAOxygPtS695L/$_81.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="big" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/390AAOxygPtS695L/$_79.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/390AAOxygPtS695L/$_78.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/390AAOxygPtS695L/$_77.JPG"/>
      </pic:picture>
      <pic:picture>
        <pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/MTAyNFg3Njg=/z/eY8AAOxyUrZS695z/$_80.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="preview" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/MTAyNFg3Njg=/z/eY8AAOxyUrZS695z/$_81.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="big" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/MTAyNFg3Njg=/z/eY8AAOxyUrZS695z/$_79.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/MTAyNFg3Njg=/z/eY8AAOxyUrZS695z/$_78.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/MTAyNFg3Njg=/z/eY8AAOxyUrZS695z/$_77.JPG"/>
      </pic:picture>
      <pic:picture>
        <pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/tKgAAMXQVERS696V/$_80.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="preview" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/tKgAAMXQVERS696V/$_81.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="big" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/tKgAAMXQVERS696V/$_79.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/tKgAAMXQVERS696V/$_78.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/tKgAAMXQVERS696V/$_77.JPG"/>
      </pic:picture>
    </pic:pictures>
  </ad:ad>
  <ad:ad id="1046912276">
    <ad:price>
      <types:currency-iso-code>
        <types:value localized-label="£">GBP</types:value>
      </types:currency-iso-code>
      <types:amount>130</types:amount>
    </ad:price>
    <ad:title>BEYONCE MRS CARTER SHOW**TOP PRICE SEATS* REDUCED PRICE!!</ad:title>
    <ad:ad-status>
      <ad:value>ACTIVE</ad:value>
    </ad:ad-status>
    <ad:start-date-time>2014-01-31T17:56:01.000Z</ad:start-date-time>
    <feat:features-active/>
    <cat:category id="84">
      <cat:id-name>pop-music-tickets</cat:id-name>
      <cat:localized-name>Pop</cat:localized-name>
    </cat:category>
    <loc:locations>
      <loc:location id="22010">
        <loc:id-name>birmingham-city-centre</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>Birmingham City Centre</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
      <loc:location id="10000392">
        <loc:id-name>uk</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>United Kingdom</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
      <loc:location id="10000393">
        <loc:id-name>england</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>England</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
      <loc:location id="11000043">
        <loc:id-name>west-midlands</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>West Midlands</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
      <loc:location id="10000347">
        <loc:id-name>birmingham</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>Birmingham</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
    </loc:locations>
    <pic:pictures>
      <pic:picture>
        <pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDQ1MQ==/z/OAIAAMXQVT9S6-Ow/$_80.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="preview" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDQ1MQ==/z/OAIAAMXQVT9S6-Ow/$_81.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="big" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDQ1MQ==/z/OAIAAMXQVT9S6-Ow/$_79.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDQ1MQ==/z/OAIAAMXQVT9S6-Ow/$_78.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDQ1MQ==/z/OAIAAMXQVT9S6-Ow/$_77.JPG"/>
      </pic:picture>
    </pic:pictures>
  </ad:ad>
  <ad:ad id="1046912270">
    <ad:price>
      <types:currency-iso-code>
        <types:value localized-label="£">GBP</types:value>
      </types:currency-iso-code>
      <types:amount>0</types:amount>
    </ad:price>
    <ad:title>Brand New All Bedrooms Furniture - Best Quality &amp; Exclusive Offers</ad:title>
    <ad:ad-status>
      <ad:value>ACTIVE</ad:value>
    </ad:ad-status>
    <ad:start-date-time>2014-01-31T17:56:01.000Z</ad:start-date-time>
    <feat:features-active/>
    <cat:category id="681">
      <cat:id-name>other-bedroom-furniture</cat:id-name>
      <cat:localized-name>Other Bedroom Furniture &amp; Accs</cat:localized-name>
    </cat:category>
    <loc:locations>
      <loc:location id="10000344">
        <loc:id-name>london</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>London</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
      <loc:location id="10000392">
        <loc:id-name>uk</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>United Kingdom</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
      <loc:location id="10000393">
        <loc:id-name>england</loc:id-name>
        <loc:localized-name>England</loc:localized-name>
      </loc:location>
    </loc:locations>
    <pic:pictures>
      <pic:picture>
        <pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/S84AAOxy63FS6-No/$_80.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="preview" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/S84AAOxy63FS6-No/$_81.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="big" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/S84AAOxy63FS6-No/$_79.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/S84AAOxy63FS6-No/$_78.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/S84AAOxy63FS6-No/$_77.JPG"/>
      </pic:picture>
      <pic:picture>
        <pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/eHMAAOxyRhBS6-NK/$_80.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="preview" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/eHMAAOxyRhBS6-NK/$_81.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="big" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/eHMAAOxyRhBS6-NK/$_79.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/eHMAAOxyRhBS6-NK/$_78.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/eHMAAOxyRhBS6-NK/$_77.JPG"/>
      </pic:picture>
      <pic:picture>
        <pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/VaIAAOxyOMdS6-NV/$_80.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="preview" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/VaIAAOxyOMdS6-NV/$_81.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="big" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/VaIAAOxyOMdS6-NV/$_79.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/VaIAAOxyOMdS6-NV/$_78.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/VaIAAOxyOMdS6-NV/$_77.JPG"/>
      </pic:picture>
      <pic:picture>
        <pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/KdYAAOxyVaBS6-Na/$_80.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="preview" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/KdYAAOxyVaBS6-Na/$_81.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="big" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/KdYAAOxyVaBS6-Na/$_79.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/KdYAAOxyVaBS6-Na/$_78.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/KdYAAOxyVaBS6-Na/$_77.JPG"/>
      </pic:picture>
      <pic:picture>
        <pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/mEwAAOxyOlhS6-Nh/$_80.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="preview" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/mEwAAOxyOlhS6-Nh/$_81.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="big" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/mEwAAOxyOlhS6-Nh/$_79.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/mEwAAOxyOlhS6-Nh/$_78.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/mEwAAOxyOlhS6-Nh/$_77.JPG"/>
      </pic:picture>
      <pic:picture>
        <pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/Va0AAOxycmBS6-Ny/$_80.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="preview" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/Va0AAOxycmBS6-Ny/$_81.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="big" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/Va0AAOxycmBS6-Ny/$_79.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/Va0AAOxycmBS6-Ny/$_78.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/Va0AAOxycmBS6-Ny/$_77.JPG"/>
      </pic:picture>
      <pic:picture>
        <pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/myoAAOxyOlhS6-N~/$_80.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="preview" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/myoAAOxyOlhS6-N~/$_81.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="big" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/myoAAOxyOlhS6-N~/$_79.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/myoAAOxyOlhS6-N~/$_78.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/myoAAOxyOlhS6-N~/$_77.JPG"/>
      </pic:picture>
      <pic:picture>
        <pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/cLoAAOxyVLNS6-OE/$_80.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="preview" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/cLoAAOxyVLNS6-OE/$_81.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="big" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/cLoAAOxyVLNS6-OE/$_79.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/cLoAAOxyVLNS6-OE/$_78.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/NDUwWDYwMA==/z/cLoAAOxyVLNS6-OE/$_77.JPG"/>
      </pic:picture>
      <pic:picture>
        <pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/MjgzWDQwMA==/z/V6EAAOxycmBS6-OJ/$_80.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="preview" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/MjgzWDQwMA==/z/V6EAAOxycmBS6-OJ/$_81.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="big" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/MjgzWDQwMA==/z/V6EAAOxycmBS6-OJ/$_79.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/MjgzWDQwMA==/z/V6EAAOxycmBS6-OJ/$_78.JPG"/>
        <pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://i.domainimg.com/00/s/MjgzWDQwMA==/z/V6EAAOxycmBS6-OJ/$_77.JPG"/>
      </pic:picture>
    </pic:pictures>
  </ad:ad>
  <types:paging>
    <types:numFound>960522</types:numFound>
    <types:link rel="self" href="https://device-api.domainnone.com/api/ads?locationId=10000392&amp;categoryId=2549&amp;page=0&amp;size=2&amp;_ver=1.17"/>
    <types:link rel="next" href="https://device-api.domainnone.com/api/ads?locationId=10000392&amp;categoryId=2549&amp;page=1&amp;size=2&amp;_ver=1.17"/>
  </types:paging>
  <ad:ads-search-options>
    <ad:locationId>10000392</ad:locationId>
    <ad:categoryId>2549</ad:categoryId>
    <ad:sortType>
      <types:value>DATE_DESCENDING</types:value>
    </ad:sortType>
  </ad:ads-search-options>
  <ad:ads-search-histograms/>
</ad:ads>
```

If you help me I will make you famous !

Comment: If you reduce your XML to the instructive minimum, format it properly, demonstrate what you've tried, what exactly failed, and then ask a precise question, I`ll build you a stairway to heaven ;-)

Comment: The original xml provided 30 items and it seems that 4 ( though I requested only 2) is the minimum I can get. I don't want to manually remove items b/c most likely the XML will get broken as I don't understand it

Comment: take a look at this, as a quick example https://eval.in/96752

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic transformation will not work. But you can use Xpath to fetch data from XML and build up your own data structures (arrays, objects, ...), much like you would with SQL with data from a database.

I don't use SimpleXML but directly DOM for that (SimpleXML is a wrapper for DOM). First you need to load you XML into a DOM document, create an Xpath object for it an register the namespaces your data is in. You can define your own aliases independent from the XML source, but in the examples I will use the same.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
//$dom->load($xmlFile);
$dom->loadXml($xmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('ad', 'http://www.ebayclassifiedsgroup.com/schema/ad/v1');
$xpath->registerNamespace('cat', 'http://www.ebayclassifiedsgroup.com/schema/category/v1');
```

Now it is possible to use DOMXpath::evaluate() to fetch data from the XML. Depending on the expression, the result will be a list of nodes or a scalar. An expression like `//element-name` will return a list, but `count(//element-name`) a number. The second argument of evaluate() is the context, the third should always be FALSE if you have namespaces.

```
$result = array();
$ads = $xpath->evaluate('/ad:ads/ad:ad', NULL, FALSE);
foreach ($ads as $ad) {
  $categories = [];
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('cat:category', $ad, FALSE) as $category) {
    $categories[$category->getAttribute('id')] = [
      'name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(cat:id-name)', $category, FALSE),
      'title' => $xpath->evaluate('string(cat:localized-name)', $category, FALSE)
    ];
  }
  $result[] = [
    'id' => $ad->getAttribute('id'),
    'title' => $xpath->evaluate('string(ad:title)', $ad, FALSE),
    'categories' => $categories
  ];
}
```

SimpleXMLs xpath() method works the same, with one big difference - it can only return lists, no scalars.